# Probability of a letter being in a four letter word.

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you have a word with 4 available slots, take the word "bake" as an example. You want to compute the probability of a letter (from the English alphabet) being in a slot of the word. So what's the probability that "b" will be in the first slot, "a" in the second slot, "k" in the third and "e" in the fourth slot. I need the individual probabilities of for a letter being in the correct slot of the word.

Every letter in the English alphabet is available, the repetition of a letter is limited to the desired word so, for the word bake since all letters are different, there is no repetition.

For some reason the first thing that came to mind was the binomial distribution, but I don't think that answers my question. Although I still do think I could use this probably as "the probability of getting all 4 letters of the word in the correct slots"

Is the probability of getting a letter in a particular slot just: $({1\over4}) $ $({1 \over 26}) = 0.009615$ ?

As for the binomial distribution, would this be correct:

$$P(X=4)= {4 \choose 4}{0.03846}^{4}(1-0.03846)^{0}$$

Where $p= {1\over26} = 0.03846$ and $n = 4, x=4$

Comment: There is a good bit of missing information in this question.  What letters are available to use?  The entire alphabet, or just the letters "a,b,e,k"?  Are letters able to be repeated?

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully that gives more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every letter in the alphabet is available and repetition is allowed, our sample space consists of all "four letter strings" which includes: aaaa, aaab, aaac, ..., abaa, abab,... zzzz, for a total of $26^{4}$ different available "words."

To calculate the probability that the first letter in the word is in fact a "b", you can count how many four letter strings begin with a "b" and divide by the total number of possible strings.  As such $Pr(\text{first is a "b"}) = \frac{26^3}{26^4} = \frac{1}{26}$.  (equivalently, you can notice that the remaining spaces in the word don't matter)

Similarly the other spaces will have probability $\frac{1}{26}$ to also be filled with their respective desired letters.

The probability of ending with the word "bake" in this scenario is, as you correctly guessed $(\frac{1}{26})^4$, as each "word" in our sample space is equally likely, and only one occurrence of the word "bake".

---

If letters are not allowed to be repeated, but all letters are available for use, our sample space then is: abcd, abce, abcf,... bacd, bace,... zyxw for a total of $26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23$ different "words" available.  The probability of each letter individually appearing in their correct spots remains $\frac{1}{26}$, **however**, the sample space size is smaller, only $26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23$.  As such the probability is no longer $(\frac{1}{26})^4$ but is instead $\frac{1}{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23}$.  This can be used as proof then that the events "first slot is b", "second slot is a", etc... are not **independent** from one another.

---

If the only letters available to use are "a,b,e,k" with letters being allowed to be repeated then our sample space consists of words: aaaa, aaab, aaae, aaak, aaba, aabb, aabe,..., kkke, kkkk, for a total of $4^4$ different such words.

Similarly to above we calculate the probability for each individual letter to appear in its respective place to be $\frac{1}{4}$, and the probability of ending with the word "bake" as $\frac{1}{4^4}$

---

If our available letters are again "a,b,e,k" and letters are not allowed to be repeated, then our sample space consists of the words: abek, abke, aebk, aekb, akbe, akeb,..., keba, for a total of $4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ different words available.

Again, similarly to before, we calculate the probability of a letter appearing in its desired location to be $\frac{1}{4}$, and the probability of ending with the word "bake" as $\frac{1}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1} = \frac{1}{24}$, which again can be used as proof that the events are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a total of $4! = 24$ different permutations of `bake` which you can generate, each occurs with equal frequency since all letters are different.

You are asking what is a chance to actually end up with the word `bake` itself -- and it should be $1/24$ in total...

Comment: Ok, I understand what you've just explained but I also want to know what's the probability of getting the individuals letters in the correct slot. So what is the probability of getting "b" in the first slot. I need these individual probabilities for each letter.